# I can't join my friend's world in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, technical-issues, windows-10

I can't join my friends. If I do, I need to wait a long time after which a screen shows `Unable to connect to world`. I've tried restarting my PC but still it won't work. If I go into my world it says `Oops! Your Microsoft account was disconnected. To invite more players, sign in on the main menu and restart your world`. But I am signed in. And then Minecraft crashed with computer and I was faced with the blue screen of death (BSOD).

- I use Bedrock Edition 1.17.41
- BSOD stop code was `video_tdr_failuer`

I got an answer [here](https://rtm-minecraft.mw-directly.com/index.html), which told me

> There is one more thing you can try: re-add your friend.
>
> Some players have reported that after reloading their private world, they’re able to connect to their friends’ world. Somehow it works for many users on all platforms.
>
> If Minecraft is not allowed in the Firewall, the “*Unable to connect to world*” issue can happen. You can connect to the internet but can’t join each other’s world. So check the Firewall settings and ensure the Minecraft executable file “*javaw.exe*” is allowed in the Firewall.
>
> Outdated network drivers may cause the “Unable to connect to world” issue. So you can try to update the network driver to fix the problem.
>
> Check you and your friends’ settings in Xbox.com. The changed settings may be the reason why you’re unable to connect to the world. Find "Join multiplayer games" and make sure it’s set to "Allow".
>
> Some antivirus software may block some features in Minecraft so that you can encounter the “unable to connect to world” issue. If you have installed antivirus software on your computer, you can disable it temporarily and check to see if the problem is resolved.

But I have a lot of friends (about 189)!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thats so weird.  Are you sure your computer is intact and doesn't do other strange things? The BSOD error suggests you should simply wait a bit, or that you have a bad video card. Otherwise if the world still refuses to load with such error then try to make him add you as an OP (operator) on the world. This worked for me once

Comment: @mindstormboi   After BSoD my chrome browser keeps turning black and then a white windows 7 window opens then back to normal. This event on my browser keeps happening frequently yesterday after the BSoD

Comment: Well I geniuenly don't know much about that. I saw a long time ago that someone had a problem when opening google chrome it would flash the new tab page and close immediately. There was no unique title so there's no chance I'm finding that post again. I'm not the most tech savy so I dont even have anymore suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would try re-adding that friend if you haven't already. If that doesn't work, ask him to make a new world or copy the one you want to join.

Comment: But I've need to press 189×2 buttons

Answer (score -1):

It could be your version of Java is outdated so it can't connect to the server. Update your Java  version and try again.

Comment: Hello, This is bedrock and not java